# Skype web client, call button is always disabled

Tags: 18.04, skype

Before latest Skype update (months ago), I was able to make calls from the Skype web-client.
Now the call button is always disabled.

This is happening on Chromium 75.0.3770.90 on Kubuntu 18.04.

When I put the mouse on the button a tooltip says that my browser does not support calls or video-calls (which is not true 'cause Google Hangouts works like a charm).

I tried to:

- use Firefox
- clear all cookies and application data for web.skype.com
- set the user agent to be the Microsoft Edge's one (version 14)

but the call button remains disabled.

I would like to know if this is happening only to me, and if someone has a workaround / fix.